# Consultas lentas en sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

indices de la tabla ma_tm_aperturaot:
co_equipo,co_sucu,co_serie_inspeccion,nu_inspeccion (Clustered)

ma_tcorden_trab:

- co_equipo,co_sucu,co_serie,co_tipdocu,nu_ordent(Clustered)

ma_tdtrabadi_ord:

- No tiene

dr_tmequipo:

- co_equipo (Clustered)

esa es la informacion que veo acerca de las tablas

---

Buen dia, tengo un problema grande...
Tengo las siguientes 2 vistas

```
create view vw_indi_fecha_inspeccion
as
select
        a.co_sucu,
        a.nu_inspeccion,
        d.co_linea,
        a.co_equipo,
        convert(date,a.fe_recepcion) as 'Fecha de recepcion',
        dbo.fecha_minima(a.nu_inspeccion,a.co_equipo) as 'Fecha inspeccion'
from ma_tmapertura_ot a
inner join dr_tmequipo d on a.co_equipo=d.co_equipo
where a.co_sucu = '01'
group by a.nu_inspeccion,
        d.co_linea,
        a.co_equipo,fe_recepcion,a.co_sucu
```

Y:

```
create view vw_indi_fecha_aperturaot
as
select
  c.co_linea, a.co_sucu, a.nu_inspeccion, a.co_equipo,
  min(fe_fecha_tareo) as 'Fecha apertura' 
from ma_tcorden_trab a
inner join ma_tdtrabadi_ord b on a.co_serie=b.co_serie 
   and a.co_tipdocu = b.co_tipdocu 
   and a.nu_ordent = b.nu_ordentr 
   and a.co_sucu = b.co_sucu
inner join dr_tmequipo c on a.co_equipo = c.co_equipo
where nu_inspeccion is not null and a.co_sucu like '%01%'
group by a.co_sucu, a.nu_inspeccion, a.co_equipo, c.co_linea
```

Cuando les hago un select por separa a cada 1, no tarda ni 1 seg. Cuando les hago un join y quiero sacar su diferencia de fechas, tarda 2 min. ¿Saben por que?

```
select a.co_linea,
  a.nu_inspeccion,
  a.co_equipo,
  a.[Fecha de recepcion],
  datediff(DAY,a.[Fecha inspeccion], b.[Fecha apertura]) 
    as 'Días para empezar a trabajar'
from vw_indi_fecha_inspeccion a
left join vw_indi_fecha_aperturaot b on a.nu_inspeccion = b.nu_inspeccion
where b.[Fecha apertura] is not null
```

Comment: No está clara la estructura de base de datos que tenés, habría que ver que índices tenes creados, etc. Pero, puede la lentitud puede venir por dos motivos, por la condición de JOIN, nu_inspeccion no está como indice en las tablas, o bien por la condición del where de la consulta, [Fecha apertura] en este caso sería deseable que hubiera un índice por dicha columna. Ejecutaste el plan de consulta? Los select que haces por separado, son con alguna condición?

Comment: Bienvenido Jesus Cuadros a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Imposible saber, sin conocer estrucuras e índices de la tabla o minímamente el query plan. Un truco que a veces funciona es insertar la salida de las dos vistas en tablas temporales (agregando índice por nu_inspeccion) y luego hacer el join con estas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, acabo de editar el post, con los datos que sugeriste a ver si me puede ayudar

Comment: Por favor ejecuta: sp_help vw_indi_fecha_aperturaot go y nos compartes la salida

Comment: Se necesita un plan de ejecución, la definición de la función fecha_minima y la estructura de tablas e índices en formato T-SQL. Además, sería bueno que indiques un aproximado de la cantidad de filas que manejas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aca te comparto algunas consideraciones que debes tomar en cuenta al momento de crear una vista en SQL Server, de igual forma te pongo un [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) hacia la documentacion oficial en español donde abordan mas ampliamente este tema.

### **Debes considerar lo siguiente:**

- Las vistas al crearse guardan el resultado en una estructura no
  indizada por lo que al listar una vista con algún tipo de orden el
  consumo de recursos de SQL Server puede perjudicar el rendimiento del
  servidor.
- Después de crear una vista es recomendable crear en esta un índice
  agrupado como su clave primaria y los índices no agrupados necesarios
  para realizar las consultas en la vista de manera mas óptima.
- Para crear índices en la vista se crea con Create Index de igual
  forma que se utilizan en la creación de índices en tablas.
- La vista tiene que estar ligada a un esquema, por lo que al crear la
  vista debemos incluir la cláusula With SchemaBinding.  Al crear la
  vista,  debe incluirse de manera obligatoria el esquema donde se
  encuentra la tablas o tablas origen de esta.

Ahora bien, enfocandonos en tu planteamiento, para poder mejorar los tiempos de respuesta vamos a crear un indice agrupado para cada vista y tambien indices no agrupados para los campos de las vistas utilizados en el where y join de la consulta.

### **Aca tienes el codigo:**

---

**Agregando la cláusula With SchemaBinding en la creacion de las vistas:**

```
create view vw_indi_fecha_inspeccion
With SchemaBinding
as
select
        a.co_sucu,
        a.nu_inspeccion,
        d.co_linea,
        a.co_equipo,
        convert(date,a.fe_recepcion) as 'Fecha de recepcion',
        dbo.fecha_minima(a.nu_inspeccion,a.co_equipo) as 'Fecha inspeccion'
from ma_tmapertura_ot a
inner join dr_tmequipo d on a.co_equipo=d.co_equipo
where a.co_sucu = '01'
group by a.nu_inspeccion,
        d.co_linea,
        a.co_equipo,fe_recepcion,a.co_sucu
go



create view vw_indi_fecha_aperturaot
With SchemaBinding
as
select c.co_linea,a.co_sucu,a.nu_inspeccion,a.co_equipo,min(fe_fecha_tareo) as 'Fecha apertura' from ma_tcorden_trab a
inner join ma_tdtrabadi_ord b on a.co_serie=b.co_serie and a.co_tipdocu=b.co_tipdocu 
                                                       and a.nu_ordent=b.nu_ordentr 
                                                       and a.co_sucu=b.co_sucu
inner join dr_tmequipo c on a.co_equipo=c.co_equipo
where nu_inspeccion is not null and a.co_sucu like '%01%'
group by a.co_sucu,a.nu_inspeccion,a.co_equipo,c.co_linea
go


select a.co_linea,
a.nu_inspeccion,
a.co_equipo,
a.[Fecha de recepcion],
datediff(DAY,a.[Fecha inspeccion], b.[Fecha apertura]) as 'Días para empezar a trabajar'
from vw_indi_fecha_inspeccion a
left join vw_indi_fecha_aperturaot b on a.nu_inspeccion=b.nu_inspeccion
where b.[Fecha apertura] is not null
```

**Crear indice agrupado para las vistas:**

```
    Create unique clustered index vw_indi_fecha_inspeccionIDX on
    vw_indi_fecha_inspeccion (co_sucu)
    go

    Create unique clustered index vw_indi_fecha_aperturaotIDX on
    vw_indi_fecha_aperturaot (co_sucu)
    go
```

**Creando indices para campos del Join y Where:**

```
    Create index Vista_inspeccion_nu_inspeccionIDX on
    vw_indi_fecha_inspeccion (nu_inspeccion)
    go

    Create index Vista_aperturaot_nu_inspeccionIDX on
    vw_indi_fecha_aperturaot (nu_inspeccion)
    go

    Create index Vista_aperturaot_fecha_aperturaIDX on
    vw_indi_fecha_aperturaot (Fecha apertura)
    go
```

Comment: Estás hablando de vistas indexadas, las cuales no son aplicables a este problema porque las vistas que se mencionan no pueden cumplir los requisitos necesarios.

Comment: No fue la solucion, pero me llevo a ella, investigue un poco mas sobre los indices y lo pude reducir de 2 min a 8 segundos, gracias por tu aporte no sabia que podia indexar una vista